# bootstrap-toggle switch is showing up as a checkbox

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, toggle, togglebutton

I have a ToggleSwitch component in react which I have made using `bootstrap-toggle`. But it is showing up as a checkbox and not as a toggle switch. Any help on this how to make it work?

**ToggleSwitch.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap-toggle/css/bootstrap-toggle.css";

class ToggleSwitch extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="toggle-switch">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          data-toggle="toggle"
          data-on="Ready"
          data-off="Not Ready"
          data-onstyle="success"
          data-offstyle="danger"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ToggleSwitch;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably something wrong with the order in which JavaScript files are being called.

For CSS call the necessary files:

- Bootstrap 4
- Bootstrap4-toggle

For JavaScript, call the files in this order:

- jQuery Slim
- Bootstrap 4
- Bootstrap4-toggle

Working snippet:

```js
const element = (
  <div className="toggle-switch">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      data-toggle="toggle"
      data-on="Ready"
      data-off="Not Ready"
      data-onstyle="success"
      data-offstyle="danger"
    />
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  element,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I saw that the latest one is `bootstrap4-toggle`. If  I use that, no such error is showing in the console but the checkbox problem persists.

Comment: I see. I tested here and it worked just fine. Edited the answer, I believe it has to do with the order of the JS being called.

Comment: I did a `import "popper/dist/umd/popper.min.js";` and it is showing me a module not found error

Comment: Here are my  imports `import "jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js";
import "popper/dist/umd/popper.min.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap4-toggle/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css";` 

Are they okay?

Comment: You are calling Bootstrap and Boostrap-toggle CSS, but not the JavaScript files. In addition, you should call CSS before any JavaScript. Probably popper is not installed. It is required for other Bootstrap features. If you are not using Bootstrap anywhere else, test without it.

Comment: `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap4-toggle/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css";
import "jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
import "bootstrap4-toggle/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js";` 
Reordered them based on your comment and put Jquery above all of them, shows  `ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`

Comment: Are you sure you have jQuery Slim installed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207982/discussion-between-proteeti-prova-and-azametzin).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the [Bootstrap toggle buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/checks-radios/#toggle-buttons) -- showing the toggle button, but also the checkbox.  **I tried the accepted answer (confirmed my Bootstrap CSS/JS file references), but it still didn't work.**

The source of my problem ended up being that I had a **custom CSS sheet with the following rule:**

```
.form-group input {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

...and my **toggle button was nested as follows:**

```
<div class="form-control">
  ...
    <input type="checkbox" class="btn-check" id="btn-check" autocomplete="off">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="btn-check">Single toggle</label>
  ...   
</div>
```

---

**SOLUTION:**
**Make sure you don't have any Bootstrap-overriding CSS rules that are changing expectations!** Once I got rid of that overriding `.form-control input` CSS rule, it worked properly!

***QUICK TEST (to see if an overriding CSS rule is your issue):** Place your toggle button outside of any other tags/classes if you can and see if it works properly.*

- *In my case, once I placed it out of the div containing the class "form-control", it worked properly, so that pointed me in the right direction -- I knew it had to do with my custom CSS rules!*

***IF QUICK TEST FAILS:** You still may have a CSS rule overriding:*

- `input`
- `input[type="checkbox"]`
- *...or one of the classes/id/names/other attributes within your input tag (e.g. class or id *`btn-check`* for Bootstrap toggle buttons)*

*In one of those cases, even placing it outside of other tags/classes won't work, so you should still check any custom/additional CSS rules/sheets for overriding!*

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap html tags has changed between bootstrap vers 4 and 5.

Make the css and js files ur using matches the tag for correct version and the above mentioned tip of loading js files can also help.

1. Correct css file for its bootstrap vers
2. Correct order of js files
3. Correct tag for the bootstrap vers.

these imports and tags work for me and toggle switch shows correctly after this:

```html
<script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class=" custom-control custom-switch">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch2">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch2"></label>
</div>
```